# When writing a compiler, how are tokens checked?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

Does a compiler use if statements when deciding what to do if a certain keyword is encounered, and should someone writing a compiler use them for most operations when checking code? Or is there a more efficient way? For example, when I test a symbol against a symbol table and it comes back as being a valid "token", do I have to use an if statement to determine what to do for every single keyword, since it seems rather inefficient, for example the pseudocode:

```
/*Each keyword/token in my compiler has a numerical representation which is what the symbol table returns back for example #define IF 0 and so on*/  
if(Token == IF){
  //This will be done to generate the AST representation for IF statements
}else if(Token == ELSE){
  //This will be done to generate the AST representation of an if statement
}else if(Token == INT){
  //This will be done to generate the AST represnetation of an integer
}
```

Comment: Note: "symbol tables" are something different and your usage here is missleading. You mean **tokens**. And there is normally no "token table". You might want to read about _compiler construction_, e.g the classic Niklaus Wirth book of the same name (free for download and quite a simple start with)..

Comment: No, I believe my usage was perfectly acceptable I have a symbol table that I check first to see if my keyword exists and is being used correctly, then if it is, the rest of the operations are done here. But I do agree with you in a since, I should have clarified.

Comment: But that is not called symbol table in a compiler! Please get the terms right. And that is not how a compiler (or an interpreter, too) works anyway. Do not invent new interpretations for well-establishe phrases. This will lead you nowhere when you ask a question.

Comment: Final clarification. Ok, so it appears as if I just got confused. IDK why I should have known what it means because of the repeat symbol error I get in Assemblers on occasion. A symbol is a specific user defined thing of a certain type, rather than a type itself

Comment: Simply put: The symbol table is where the compiler looks up names _defined_ in the parsed code to look up the type and other properties (e.g. struct, union, members, variable/constant, possibly value, etc.) if it encounters a name. Exaxtly. These are _symbols_ in the **parser**. For the **scanner/lexer**, a symbol is a charactern like `,`, `%`, `+`. And that is what you use here. But for a compiler-context, they are not that relevant, because they are normally just read from the input and formed to tokens by the lexer. You normally do not have a table to lookup, but use e.g. a state-machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of compilers do you mean?
If the performance matters, you may want something like callback, in this way, use the keyword as key and the callback function as the value, so the pseudo code would looks like this:

```
func *fp = funcTbl.get(Token);
if (fp) { fp(); }
```

You may try the recursive descent too. The function related to the keyword got called just where they are expected to be.

Last but not least, what you write is ok as well.

Comment: 1) This is C, not C++. 2) What do you mean? OP needs a parser; that would normally not use callbacks, but call the functions directly according to the structure of the grammar. If you have the same semantics at two different places in your code, you have done something wrong in your parser.

Comment: C code is perfectly acceptable in fact it is preferable here over C++ as I am not as familiar with C++ as I am C, which is why I specified C in the tags rather than C++ It will also be understandable by both C and C++ programmers meaning if someone were to have a similar question a more diverse target audience could exist.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure how you got an implication of C++ as `funcTbl.get(Token)` is valid C.  The example is a variant of recursive descent [as mentioned] parsing.

Comment: Without a declaration it is not possible to see that.

Comment: @Olaf Do you know of the answer, or something that could help me out? I don't want to learn any bad coding habits.

Comment: @TheRenegade:There are tons of books on the subject compiler construction, some are for free download.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into a few of them.

Comment: "If the performance matters" you absolutely do not want to use function pointers. This is fine advice but not for performance reasons. For performance, you're better off switching on your token and having a case label with a call of the correct function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already split your source language from string representation to a series of lexical tokens, your next step is to use a **[parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)** to build an AST from your tokens.

The parsing stage of compilation achieves two main goals:

- It checks your language for syntactic correctness, throwing an error if your input cannot be parsed according to the structure of your grammar.
- It generates an AST representation of your source code

> Does a compiler use if statements when deciding what to do if a
>   certain keyword is encountered?

No, your parser should analyse the series of lexical tokens and check them against the structure of your language's grammar.

Parsing is a well understood topic in computer science which can be approached in different ways. it cannot be trivially implemented in the example code fragment you have provided above. In a realistic programming language you need to consider that grammars can be ambiguous, and that a simple predictive parser is appropriate for all grammars and some kind of backtracking will be needed. If you do not understand this concept, I recommend you use a Parser generator for this, such as [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).

This diagram shows a simplistic overview of the most important stages of compilation and may help you to understand its pipeline structure.

[image]
This is a process which has been refined for decades by many academics about how to best 'divide and conquer' such a mammoth task. I strongly encourage you to follow it.

For further reading, check out [Modern Compiler Implementation in Java by Andrew Appel](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/).